# Last-Child inside div not working

Tags: html, css, addthis

I and using addthis share plugin and have changed background color to yellow and also added `bottom-border: of 1px`, I want to remove the bottom border from the last a which is not working for me using following css

**css**

```
div#at4-share a:last-child
{
  border-bottom: 0px solid #1f1f1f; 
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="at4-share" class="addthis_32x32_style atss atss-left addthis-animated slideInLeft at4-show">
  <a class="at4-share-btn at-svc-facebook" href="#">
    <span class=" at4-icon aticon-facebook" title="Facebook">Facebook</span>
  </a>
  <a class="at4-share-btn at-svc-twitter" href="#">
    <span class=" at4-icon aticon-twitter" title="Twitter">Twitter</span>
  </a>
  <a class="at4-share-btn at-svc-pinterest_share" href="#">
    <span class=" at4-icon aticon-pinterest_share" title="Pinterest">Pinterest</span>
  </a>
  <a class="at4-share-btn at-svc-google_plusone_share" href="#">
    <span class=" at4-icon aticon-google_plusone_share" title="Google+">Google+</span>
  </a>
  <a class="at4-share-btn at-svc-compact" href="#">
    <span class=" at4-icon aticon-compact" title="More">More</span>
  </a>
  <div id="at4-scc" class="at-share-close-control ats-transparent at4-show at4-hide-content" title="Hide">
    <div class="at4-arrow at-left">Hide</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I had tried

```
div#at4-share a:last-of-type
{
  border-bottom: 0px solid #1f1f1f; 
}
```

so i am not sure what is wrong

Comment: I know what the problem was, but just in case, if you wanted to remove the _underline_ of an `<a>`, you would need to set the `text-decoration` property, not the `border-bottom`.

Comment: Also, you start off with calling it `bottom-border`, so my advice is to run your stylesheet through a validator. http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct selector is `:last-of-type`.

```
div#at4-share > a:last-of-type
{
  border-bottom:none; /* To remove the bottom border. */
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/a9zLc4bs/1/)

Comment: I saw  `div#at4-share > a:last-of type {}` in your original post - notice the missing hyphen between `of` and `type`. Maybe just a typo, but not sure if that might have been the issue.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `:last-of-type`, because `:last-child` is `div` with text hide in this case.

```
div#at4-share a:last-of-type {border-bottom: 2px solid red;}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4y9j0z9q/

See the `:last-child` too

https://jsfiddle.net/4y9j0z9q/1/